# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un archivo php usando html?

Tags: php, html, angular, web, xampp

lamento mucho las molestias con algo tan simple, pero me ha comido la cabeza un tiempo,  estoy haciendo una pagina web (usando Xampp como servidor) y ya tengo un archivo php que se conecta a mi base de datos.

Ahora estoy haciendo la pagina desde el lado usuario con html y tengo esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Revisar Dato
    </h1>

  </div>

  <li>

    <h3>
      La forma siguiente es para recibir datos de un alumno
    </h3>
    <ul>

     <form action="api/pedido.php" method="post" >
      ID Alumno: <input type="text" name="id_est"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</html>
```

(Aclaro que es un componente.)
Tengo el llamado al archivo en un formulario como se puede ver

Tengo tanto la carpeta de Api como la de html en htdocs dentro de Xampp (no se si eso afecte), pero ambos estan en carpetas separadas:

[image: Carpeta htdocs]

Sin embargo, al correr la pagina html y llamar el php, aparece: Cannot POST api/pedido.php

¿Porque es eso?, por lo que se tengo la direccion escrita de manera correcta, ¿es porque el html esta hecho en angular (Lo corro con git bash, ng serve) o hay una etiqueta que falta?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. ¿Abres el HTML en el navegador? ¿Cuál es el contenido de `pedido.php`? ¿Cómo se llama el archivo .html? ¿Qué tiene que ver Angular en esto?

Comment: Prueba saliendo de tu actual carpeta ( ../ ), y entrando a la carpeta api, que es donde está el .php. La ruta te quedaría así  **../api/pedido.php**

Comment: Cedano, me refiero que a que inicio la pagina usando un metodo de angular (ng serve).

pedido.php es una conexion a una base de datos sql y ejecuta un Select

Comment: Prueba pasando una copia de `pedido.php` a tu carpeta `html` y usa la ruta `<form action="pedido.php" method="post" >`. Si funciona, el problema que tienes es en la ruta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas corriendo la carpeta html eso quiere decir que estas dentro y pues con

```
<form action="api/pedido.php" method="post" >
```

Esta buscando dentro de HTML la carpeta api , Debes retroceder una carpeta para conseguir la carpeta api

```
<form action="../api/pedido.php" method="post" >
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Pense algo similar, lo acabo de aplicar pero lamentablemente sigo con el mismo problema :c

Igual muchas gracias!